# How to create jquery calendar as visualforce page and tab

Tags: visualforce, calendar

I have to create a tab for my app that can display jquery calendar and I want to add some custom objects to that calendar. So, how can I do that? I suppose that I have to create a new Visualforce page representing that calendar. Is that true?

Thank you for your help. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can [upload static resources](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_resources.htm), write your Visualforce page, and [create a new tab](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=pages_tabs_create.htm&type=5) for it. Please note that this community's support for external JavaScript is very limited, so if you have jQuery-specific questions, your question might be a better fit on [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/). Also, please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) for details about what we consider on-topic and appropriate for this network.

For accessing data without Apex Code, you might want to read about [Visualforce Remote Objects](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask). We can help you understand how to use those to load/save/modify records in an object, if you have a specific question. We can also generally answer questions about troubles you might run into when using Visualforce-specific features.